# How to create a self extract setup?

Tags: windows, self-extracting

I"m using VS2008 and I made a project for my own use. I can create setup using VS utility of setup creating called deploying project. But I want a self extract setup that launch by user in easily way how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular choices are:

- [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) (along with [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) or [InnoIDE](http://www.innoide.org/))
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (builds MSI packages)

Also common, but not recommended for small projects:

- [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) (commercial, both EXE and MSI)

Answer (score 2):

as I know there are some free tools like [Zipinstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/zipinst.html) or [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Just try it. :-)